# Running scheduled / repeated tasks in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a process - currently written in NodeJS - that goes out and does task X every 5 minutes.   It might do task Y every 15 and task Z every 60.

There are actually hundreds of 'task X' and 'task Y / etc' but its the same task with different parameters.

I'd like to run this out of AWS.  Would it be better to set up a nodeJS service and do this... or better to set up smaller tasks and use a cron-esque task?  (and if so, what would that name of that service be)

Thank you...

Comment: How much time does it take for a task to complete?

Comment: Each "X" takes 5-10 seconds... but there could be hundreds of "X" tasks.   If you ran all the "X" tasks sequentially, it'd take 5-15 minutes.

Comment: Then use Lambda + CloudWatch/Event Bridge Scheduled Events and create a Lambda for each task. They can ran in parallel.